# Flutter VS Code issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Why do I get these VS Code errors after running `flutter doctor`:

```
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale hu-HU)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] VS Code, 32-bit edition
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.24.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current release of flutter does not properly detect the VSC extension because of case sensitivity errors.  If it shows up in VSCode, it's installed.  Ignore Flutter Doctor. :)

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons for this, but the most likely cause is that you have VS Code installed but not the Flutter extension.

I get the same:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.5.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
[!] VS Code, 32-bit edition
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.22.2)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Run `flutter doctor -v` for more details as it tells you to in the error message:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.5.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 0.5.4 at C:\VirtualDrives\Programs\flutter
    • Framework revision 3019ad976d (11 days ago), 2018-06-11 11:31:25 -0700
    • Engine revision d33bbff470
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.60.0.flutter-a5e41681e5

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\VirtualDrives\Programs\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\VirtualDrives\Programs\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1
    • Flutter plugin version 19.1
    • Dart plugin version 172.4343.25

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.4892.1

[!] VS Code, 32-bit edition
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.22.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```